# Javascript SOLR URL Filter Query Parser

Tags: javascript, solr, url-parsing

We do have filter queries like this in SOLR:

```
?pageSize=30&currentPage=0&q=blahblah:relevance,sortingNumber-asc:productgroup:houseHoldSoap:soapVariant:TMZ:lengthToBeginningOfEdge:381.0-to-381.0
```

Now we need a javascript object of this object. So we need to parse it somehow, to get something like this:

```
{
  pageSize: 30,
  currentPage: 0,
  sorting: ["relevance", "sortingNumber-asc"],
  filterQuery: [
        {"productgroup": "houseHoldSoap"},
        {"soapVariant": "TMZ"},
        {"lengthToBeginningOfEdge": "381.0-to-381.0" }
  ]
}
```

We tried to write our own parser because we could not find any existing library, but it's almost impossible because the syntax is so bad. For example there are key-value items like "productgroup:houseHoldSoap" but other filter values like sorting is just a single value and all are seperated by ":" ...

Is there any good way to achieve this? Like a Javascript function or SOLR library, that we can just pass the URL string and it returns a proper javascript object?

Comment: Fropm your example this doesn't seem like Solr syntax, so I'm not sure why a Solr library would be able to parse it; a Solr query would use `fq=..` and standard, repeating http query args to have multiple parameters. It would probably be a good idea to start looking at however the application receiving these parameters are parsing them?

Comment: Thanks, good question, we definetly use SOLR but could be that there is another software kinda in between. Thanks! I'll check that.